# How can I find out what a command is executing in Terminal on MacOs

Tags: macos

After I run a shell script (which call a bunch a other scripts depend on conditions. which is too complicated to understand), I can execute a command 'gdbclient' at my MacOS terminal.

But when I do 'which gdbclient' and 'alias gdbclient', it shows nothing.
Is there anyway for me to find out what 'gdbclient' is actually doing?

Comment: have you located 'gdbclient'? e.g. 
$ ``locate gdbclient``

Answer (score 1):

You can open up another terminal window and type: **ps**

That will list all the running processes.

If your script is running as a different user than the current one, you can use **ps -ef** to list all running processes.

If you know the PID of the process that ran your script, you can find all child processes via parent PID using **ps -f | grep [pid]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Activity Monitor to check things out pretty thoroughly.  To get the right privileges to see *everything* going on you can do:

```
sudo open /Applications/Utilities/Activity\ Monitor.app/
```

Answer (score 0):

Dtrace can give you some helpful information: [dtrace](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071031121823710)

Answer (score 0):

to find process 'gdbclient':

```
ps aux | grep gdbclient
```

That wont tell you what it's "doing" but that it's running